# Shape-from-shading algorithms?

Tags: code-request, computer-vision

Before I go to the effort of writing my own code, I was wondering if there is code available for shape-from-shading algorithms.  These take an image (such as a black-and-white image, such as [this](https://dissolve.com/stock-photo/Full-frame-photo-rumpled-bed-royalty-free-image/101-D1301-116-028)) and infer the three-dimensional depth map based on the lightness at a point and constraints such as smoothness of the inferred surface, or properties of the light source (e.g., a point source from a known direction).

Comment: There is [this](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Single-Image-Depth-Perception-Net-Trained-on-NYU-Depth-V2-and-Depth-in-the-Wild-Data).

Comment: Oh... very helpful... thanks so much.  (+1). Let me wait a bit to see if there is a more direct solution, but this may suffice.

Comment: There are deep learning methods that can do this inaccurately, but it's much better to have multiple photographs where either 1) you move the camera (photogrammetry) or 2) you move the light source and generate a normal map from this instead of full depth. There is also 3) you take multiple photos at different focal lengths, but that's expensive and noisy. Whatever method you choose, if you don't have multiple photos it's impossible to tell whether the shadows are due to surface depth or that's just the albedo/texture of the 'flattened' out surface.

Comment: ^ see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometric_stereo

Comment: @flinty:  Oh I know the *science* and algorithmics of shape-from-shading and photometric stereo extremely well, having published a few highly cited papers on the subject.  I'm also currently teaching it in one of the world's leading computer science departments.  I also know the many PyTorch, Caffe, and other systems.  I was hoping for something in *Mathematica* to integrate with several other *Mathematica*-based algorithms.  Of course multi-view systems are most accurate, but that is irrelevant to my case, which is inferring depth from a (single) example of an artwork.